# Java simple date formatter parse exception in remote machine

Tags: java, parsing, date, simpledateformat

In locale machine I have this code and it is executing fine..

```
DateFormat stdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss zZ (zzzz)");

String date = "Sun Mar 16 2014 10:30:00 GMT 0530 (India Standard Time)"
Calendar stcal = Calendar.getInstance();
try {
   stcal.setTime(stdf.parse(date.replace("GMT ", "UTC+")));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But I have running the same code in remote machine which is in Amazon server
which gives following parsing error,

```
java.text.ParseException: unparseable date: "Sat March 15 2014 09:00:00 UTC+1000<E. Australia Standard Time>"
```

Comment: Can you paste SimpleDateFormat object creation logic 'stdf'

Comment: It doesn't help that you haven't told us anything about `stdf`, and the value you appear to be parsing on the Amazon server doesn't seem to match the format of the sample. (It doesn't start with `Start:` for example.)

Comment: Hi sorry i missed that one now i edited the post with added stdf var

Answer (score 0):

Update the replace content as below :

```
stcal.setTime(stdf.parse(date.replace("GMT ", "UTC +")));
```

Comment: No its not working same problem I tested in locale and in remote, Local host working fine but in remote it is not working @Youngistan

Comment: @chinmayahd what exception you receive now on remote ??

Comment: java.text.ParseException: unparseable date: "Sat March 15 2014 09:00:00 UTC+1000<E. Australia Standard Time> Same exception

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49391/discussion-between-youngistan-and-chinmayahd)

Answer (score 0):

The date in stackTrace is :-

Sat **March** 15 2014 09:00:00 UTC+1000

However, in local your date is :-

String date = "Sun **Mar** 16 2014 10:30:00 GMT 0530 (India Standard Time)"

For running the code with date you are using in remote machine, your dateformat should be :-

```
DateFormat stdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "EEE MMMMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss zZ (zzzz)");
```

Notice 5 Ms instead of 3Ms.